# Handling lots of data points in Sinter Graphing

Tags: stim, sinter

Sinter is really awesome for streamlining my circuit runs. It was incredibly easy to set up and switch into, and it's very fast. The `save_resume_filepath` is a life saver for long runs.

I'm a little confused on how to use the graphing. When I have, say, 100 different points on my plot, I end up with a graph whose individual points are so densely packed together that I  get less of a line and more of a melted-icecream sort of look.

Is there a way to ask sinter to plot these points with a different linewidth or linestyle. I know these options exist in matplotlib but I'm not sure if it's possible to interface with matplotlib in this way via sinter.

I like how natural and easy grouping/plotting different aspects of the data (circuit type, noise model, etc.) is in Sinter since it's a one line change to the `group_func` arg. I'd really love to switch over to Sinter graphing completely if I can figure out how to graph lots of points.

Example of the really close points:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `plot_args_func` argument of [`sinter.plot_error_rate`](https://github.com/quantumlib/Stim/blob/main/doc/sinter_api.md#sinter.plot_error_rate) to customize how the lines look. It should return a dictionary where the keys are arguments to give to [`matplotlib.pyplot.plot`](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.plot.html). Here's an example that makes distance 5 curves use 'x' markers and other curves be black with no markers:

```
def custom_plot_args_func(
    curve_index: int,  # a unique incrementing integer for each curve
    curve_group_key: Any,  # what group_func returned
    stats: List[sinter.TaskStats],  # the data points on the curve
) -> Dict[str, Any]:
    stat = stats[0]
    if stat.json_metadata['d'] == 5:
        return {'marker': 'x'}
    return {'color': 'black', 'marker': ''}

sinter.plot_error_rate(
    ax=ax,
    stats=stats,
    ...,
    plot_args_func=custom_plot_args_func,
)
```

You can also do this from the command line. It tries to make things a bit more succinct by pulling out values like `metadata = stats[0].json_metadata` for you to use:

```
sinter plot ... --plot_args_func "{'marker': 'x'} if metadata['d'] == 5 else {'marker': '', 'color': 'black'}" ...
```

---

Lastly, always remember there is the option of reading the csv data and plotting it for yourself. Sinter is not intended to be a full fledged plotting library; only a quick succinct plotting library for circuit error data. If you want to heavily customize a plot you will eventually need to start reading the data for yourself and giving it to `matplotlib` or `seaborn` or some other general plotting library. Sinter does provide some tools to help with this, like:

- [`sinter.stats_from_csv_files(path)`](https://github.com/quantumlib/Stim/blob/main/doc/sinter_api.md#sinter.stats_from_csv_files) will take care of reading the file and adding up the rows that are from the same circuit, and then return a list of `sinter.TaskStats` objects (they have fields like `shots`, `errors`, and `json_metadata`).
- [`sinter.group_by(iterable, key=func)`](https://github.com/quantumlib/Stim/blob/main/doc/sinter_api.md#sinter.group_by) will give back a dictionary from key to list of items that had that key, which is useful for grouping into curves.
- [`sinter.fit_binomial`](https://github.com/quantumlib/Stim/blob/main/doc/sinter_api.md#sinter.fit_binomial) for getting Bayesian-style uncertainty ranges
- [`sinter.fit_line_slope`](https://github.com/quantumlib/Stim/blob/main/doc/sinter_api.md#sinter.fit_line_slope) for getting Bayesian-style uncertainty ranges on the lambda of a code
- [`sinter.fit_line_y_at_x`](https://github.com/quantumlib/Stim/blob/main/doc/sinter_api.md#sinter.fit_line_y_at_x) for getting Bayesian-style uncertainty ranges on the footprint of a code
- [`sinter.better_sorted_str_terms`](https://github.com/quantumlib/Stim/blob/main/doc/sinter_api.md#sinter.better_sorted_str_terms) is a key function you can give to python's `sorted` such that `a12` will come after `a2` instead of before
- [`sinter.shot_error_rate_to_piece_error_rate`](https://github.com/quantumlib/Stim/blob/main/doc/sinter_api.md#sinter.shot_error_rate_to_piece_error_rate)
- etc

Comment: Thank you! This was very helpful!